# Flutter submit login Bloc using stream " RxDart"

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc, rxdart

I am writing a flutter app with Bloc architecture with go API, and I have some issue i want when I Press in my login button, after I retrieve the result that if the username and password is valid. I will return texte "error username and password not valid" if was an error .

sorry for my bad English.

```
//my bloc.dart login 
class Bloc extends Validators {
  final _email = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _password = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  //add to the stram

  Stream<String> get email => _email.stream.transform(validateEmail);
  Stream<String> get password => _password.stream.transform(validatePassword);
  Stream<bool> get submitValid =>
      Observable.combineLatest2(email, password, (e, p) => true);

  //change Data
  Function(String) get changeEmail => _email.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changePassword => _password.sink.add;

  submit() {
    print('your email is :' + _email.value);
    print('your password is :' + _password.value);
    // result = http request 
    // show the error to the user if there are  

  }

  dispose() {
    _email.close();
    _password.close();
  }
}
```

//my validator.dart

```
class Validators {
  final validateEmail = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (String email, EventSink<String> sink) {
        if (email.contains('@')) {
          sink.add(email);
        } else {
          sink.addError('Enter a valid email');
        }
      }
  );

  final validatePassword = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (String password, EventSink<String> sink) {
        if (password.length > 3) {
          sink.add(password);
        } else {
          sink.addError('Enter must be at least 4 characters');
        }
      }
  );
}
```

//submit flutter widget

```
Widget submitButton(Bloc bloc) => StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: bloc.submitValid,
        builder: (context, snap) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (!snap.hasData) ? null : bloc.submit,
                child: Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              Text((!snap.hasError) ? "" : "The result of the api" )
            ],
          );
        },
      );
```

Comment: try to change your onPressed to: onPressed: (!snap.hasData) ? () {} : () => bloc.submit(),

Comment: Check out [flutter_form_bloc](https://github.com/GiancarloCode/form_bloc/tree/master/packages/flutter_form_bloc), you can achieve what you want but with much less code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that, because you have to add an error to a stream, and for that you need StreamController. For example, you could do next: 
`_email.addError("some_error");` and then that error will get caught by stream builder. I this will help you.